# Why was Benj Clarke trying to blow up Iceland?

Tags: ra

In the [Ragdoll Physicist](https://qntm.org/ragdoll) chapter of Ra, Benj Clarke is trying to blow up Iceland. Can it be inferred what he tries to achieve by that? At first it would seem logical, if he was indeed being ...

> ... possessed by Tanako, as he later lies to Laura, stating that he wants to break through the abstraction layer called thaumic magic, to get to the "real" magic. However, it later turns out that he was not possessed by Tanako at all, but by Ra itself. Actually, by the few surviving nanomachines which survived reprogramming after Ra lost the Abstract War, and which formed into the "Glass Man" instance of Ra. And this instance of Ra has only one objective: reactivate the main instance of Ra in the Sun, by resurrecting Rachel so it can steal the key from her brain.

But how would blowing up Iceland help in achieving that objective?

> Actually, it could have resulted in Laura being killed forever, and Ra needed Laura to resurrect Rachel. Or might it be that this was the event when Laura learned (or Ra verified) how to bring back matter from the T-world? (because it seems her and her sister's bodies died in the real world in the Icelandic incident, and they somehow escaped from the T-World back into reality)

Answer (score 1):

Ra couldn't assume that Laura would have the ability to resurrect Rachel. If that isn't an option, what is the next course of action for Shard-Ra to resurrect Sun-Ra? One of the main advantages of the key is the access to the massive amounts of energy. Shard-Ra probably already had the programming needed to reactivate, as demonstrated with the quine. Thus the only thing it needed was a massive energy packet of thaumonuclear proportions.